# error on javascript dom appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each($('#income_ranges').children(), function(key, value) {
  var field_row = value.getElementsByTagName("input");

  $.each(field_row, function(key, value) {
    if(value.value == "") {
        value.appendChild("<div> cant be blank </div>");
    }
  })
})
```

I want to append the following div to value but i get an error stating that value.appendChild is not a function.

in my code value is a HTMLInputElement and i want to input the div just below the element but i get that annoying error.

```
<input class="string required" id="lender_dsr_max_threshold_income_ranges_attributes_1437717712398_income_range" name="lender_dsr_max_threshold[income_ranges_attributes][1437717712398][income_range]" type="text">
```

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: as an aside, you can change `$('#income_ranges').children()` to simply `$('#incomes_ranges > *')`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here,

1. `value` is a input element, so it can't have child elements
2. [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) takes a node as its parameter, not a string

Since you want to add the `div` after the `input` which is a descendant of `#income_ranges`, use [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)(to select the `input` elements) and [after()](https://api.jquery.com/after)(to insert the div as the `input`s next sibling)

```
$('#income_ranges input').filter(function () {
    return this.value == ''
}).after('<div> cant be blank </div>')
```

Comment: so how do i append it beneath the input element?

Comment: i have multiple input elements hence the .each() function to iterate through the children of $('#income_ranges')

Comment: i need to specify the exact input element that i want to append to

Comment: You mean the blank input's

Comment: your tips made me figure it out. your answer is correct but not just exactly how i want it to be. thats all but @arun answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your suggestions. I solved it like this

```
$.each($('#income_ranges').children(), function(key, value) {
  var field_row = value.getElementsByTagName("input");

  $.each(field_row, function(key, value) {
    if(value.value == "") {
       $(this).after("<div> cant be blank </div>");
    }
  })
})
```